# Tflite object detection model crashes android application

Tags: android-studio, tensorflow, object-detection, tflite

I want to create an object detection application but as with custom object detection model but the tensorflow example object detection app crashes if i use my trained model.
link to the trained model https://github.com/SPEAR22/tfliteodmodel.git
Did something went wrong while training.

I wanted to build object detection application with my own custom dataset but tensor flow example app crashes with my custom trained model.